# Advantage of multiple socket connections

Tags: sockets, tcp, connection

I keep hearing people say, to get a better throughput you create multiple socket connection. 
But my understanding is that however many tcp sockets you open between two end points. the ip layer is still one. So not sure where this additional throughput comes from

Comment: You are correct. The 'advantage' is illusory, and it costs more packet exchanges to open and close the extra connections.

Comment: I agree to that , but what if there are long lived connections. The cost of opening these will be only a one time affair. To me it looks like throughput should be reduced as there will be more multiplex resolution happening somewhere at tcp layer.

Comment: The cost of opening and closing a connection is still higher than the cost of not doing so. The cost of 'multiplex resolution' is insignificant. Packets still have to be routed to a port and process, no matter how many of those there are.

Answer (score 1):

The additional throughput comes from increasing the amount of data sent in the first couple of round trip times (RTTs). TCP can send only IW packets the first round trip time (RTT). The amount is then doubled each RTT (slow start). If you open 4 connections you can send 4 * IW packets the first RTT. The throughput is quadrupled.

Lets say that a client requests a file that requires IW+1 packets. Opening two connections can complete the sending in one RTT, rather than two RTTS.

HOWEVER, this comes at a price. The initial packets are sent as a burst, which can cause severe congestion and packet loss.